# Como puedo crear un diccionario de palabras femeninas y masculinas?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, entrada

tengo una duda, tengo definida una funcion para restringir palabras ofensivas en mi input pero necesito un codigo para que sin importar la palabra que se ingrese, el codigo restrinja las palabras tanto en femenino como en masculino, ejemplo: perro - perra

el siguiente es mi codigo en javascript:

```js
var malasPalabras = ['perro'];

const checkMalasPalabras = (palabra) => {

var rgx = new RegExp(malasPalabras.join("|")+"|" + "/gi");
return (rgx.test(palabra));
}

$('#boton-guardar').click(() => {        
      
  var nombre = $("#nombretxt").val().toLowerCase();
  
  if(checkMalasPalabras(nombre) == true){
   swal("Ups! algo ha ocurrido", "Ingresaste una palabra indebida, intenta de nuevo", "error");
    document.getElementById("nombretxt").value = "";   
  }
```

Comment: Como info, esto es bastante subjetivo. Una palabra ofensiva depende de varios aspectos, entre ellos idioma y contexto de frase. Sería prudente que penséis una solución distinta, sino lo que restrinjan puede hacer que se pierda el significado de esta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opción sencilla es reemplazar la/s última/s letra/s si es terminación femenina por la masculina, de modo que no es necesario modificar el diccionario.

Usando esta aproximación puedes manejar un diccionario más sencillo en el que únicamente figura el masculino singular y creas aproximaciones en código para detectar las terminaciones femeninas y/o plurales. Su utilidad dependerá de la complejidad de tu sistema.

Te dejo un ejemplo. Espero que te sirva.

```js
var malasPalabras = ['perro'];
const checkMalasPalabras = (palabra) => {

var rgx = new RegExp(malasPalabras.join("|")+"|" + "/gi");
return (rgx.test(palabra));
}

$('#boton-guardar').click(() => {        
      
  var nombre = $("#nombretxt").val().toLowerCase(); 
  var lastletter = nombre.substr(nombre.length - 1);  
  if (lastletter == "a") {
   nombre = nombre.slice(0, -1)+"o"; //alert(nombre);
  }
  
  if(checkMalasPalabras(nombre)){
   
    document.getElementById("nombretxt").value = ""; 
    alert("no permitido");
  } else {
    alert("continua");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="nombretxt" id="nombretxt">
<input type="submit" id="boton-guardar">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Carmen, tu respuesta es Perfecta!

Comment: Carmen veo un inconveniente en tu respuesta neceito imprimir esa palabra pero cuando se ponen palabras en femenino se esta reemplazando la a por la o y necesito que salga el nombre bien

Comment: @AndersonRodríguez para que no reemplaze la variable nombre bastaría con usar una variable intermedia nombreComprobar = nombre.slice(0, -1)+"o"; y que sea esta la que pasas a la función CheckMalasPalabras. En este ejemplo modifiqué nombre porque no se usaba para nada más.